# Making up point from two numbers from different cells in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have two numbers in two different cells. In cell A1, I have 340. In cell B1, I have 7. Now I want to do calculation like below:

```
=A1/1.B1
```

The point here is: I want to use B1 as decimal point number, So it would be 340/1.7. However, Excel does not accept this. What would be the correct way of writing this formula? Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create a decimal of B using:

```
B1/10^LEN(B1)
```

This will divide the number in B1 by the appropriate 10,100,1000 based on the length of the number as a string.  It will thus create a decimal.

and add 1 and divide A1 by the result:

```
=A1/(1 + B1/10^LEN(B1))
```

[image]

Another method is to create a text string

```
("1." & B1)
```

the resultant math will convert it to a number. So the full formula would be:

```
=A1/("1." & B1)
```

[image]